# jQuery can removeClass but cannot addClass for element that has .on("click")

Tags: jquery, css, delegates, click

I want a box that opens on a click and closes on a the click of a button `.c-btn`. I have setup the delegated event handling on a parent div, and this allows `.speaker__item--expanded` to be removed but it fails to add `.speaker__item--collapsed`.

If I manually remove `.speaker__item--collapsed` and add `speaker__item--expanded` in dev tools, the close button then works, so I assume it's related to the way I've setup my `.on` click function but I cannot see how to fix it.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhdcd5am/

Comment: Your class names are very over complicated. The repetition of `speaker__item-XXX` makes it hard to see what's what and not very DRY. I'd suggest you move to using compound classes instead, eg. `.speaker-item.detail.basic`

Comment: Hi Rory, I'm trying to use the BEM methodology, which I know is both hated and loved. However it does make life simpler when working in a large dev team.

Comment: I'm definitely in the hate camp, but if you're using it consistently within your team there's far worse things :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's a dynamically created element you're clicking.

Just change

```
$('.c-btn').click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click','.c-btn', function() {
```

That will fix it.